# BT Web Protect blocking firebase storage urls

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

At some point yesterday (25/08/21) we started getting errors accessing any documents held in firebase storage.

I can see them in the firebase console, but if I try to view them I get an error.

The exact error depends on which browser but it was along the lines of:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
firebasestorage.googleapis.com uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

After a bit of digging, it seems specific to the BT ISP in the UK, and caused by their BT Web Protect product. If I disable Web Protect from my BT account I can access the urls again, but obviously that is not a solution I can offer to our customers. (Similarly, if I connect via a mobile hotspot on my phone, all is well)

I contacted BT who suggested I email saferbrowsing@bt.com and ask them to unblock it, so if anyone else is having this issue please do the same - the more noise on this the quicker the resolution hopefully.

To the Firebase team - is there anything you can do from your side to expedite this? Firebase Storage is a huge part of our product and it simply doesn't work for anyone on BT at the moment.

Thanks

John

Comment: I've faced similar error but when trying to use custom domain over Firebase download URLs via Cloudflare. Are you using Cloudflare by chance ?

Comment: Same problem again here, only happens on BT.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply from BT this morning saying that firebase has been unblocked, and all seems to be working again. phew!

Answer (score 0):

Several ISP's have anti-spam detection, this is used to hunt down new spikes of traffic that can seem suspicious. If you are getting faults from users from a specific ISP or geolocation, this can indicate outages or blocked requests.

The best solution is to always call their technical support and discuss what could have triggered it and remove any potential blocks from happening again.